# Reference request: levelwise detection of a morphism of $\infty$-functors being an isomorphism

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

Is there a reference for the following?

Consider quasi-categories $I,C$. Suppose that a morphism between functors $\alpha : \Delta^1 \to Fun(I,C)$ is given. Suppose that for every $i \in I$, denoting the evaluation $ev_i : Fun(I,C) \to C$, the composition $ev_i \circ \alpha$ is an isomorphism (in the homotopy category). How to show then that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism (in the homotopy category)?

Thanks

Comment: Its in Rezk's notes "stuff about quasi categories" proposition 29.10 he also references HTT 3.1.1. there.

Comment: @SaalHardali: Thank you!

Comment: You may also find that result as Theorem 5.14 in Joyal's [*The Theory of Quasi-Categories and its Applications*](http://mat.uab.cat/~kock/crm/hocat/advanced-course/Quadern45-2.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making my comment an answer to remove it from the unanswered list:

This is in Rezk's *Stuff about quasicategories* ([pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rezk/595-fal16/quasicats.pdf)), Proposition 29.10.